# SQL combine output of two SQL statements to return a boolean

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and want to make sure that data exists in BOTH tables usign SQL.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teachers WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL;
```

I want to make sure both above statements return 0. If so I want to return TRUE and else I want to return False.

Can I do this from a SQL script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is to use put these in a subquery:

```
SELECt (CASE WHEN t.cnt = 0 AND s.cnt = 0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) as flag
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM teachers
      WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL
     ) t CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt
      FROM students
      WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL
     ) s;
```

In general, though, it is more efficient to use `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS` rather than aggregation:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM teachers
                              WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL) AND
                  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM students
                              WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL)
             THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'
        END)
FROM DUAL;
```

How is this formulation more efficient?  First, the `NOT EXISTS` can stop at the first row that fails the condition.  The `COUNT(*)` always has to read the entire table, even if the first row it encounters fails the condition.  The count needs to be accurate.

Second, the condition on `students` doesn't need to be evaluated at all if the first condition is succeeds (or fails, depending on how you look at it).

Answer (score 3):

If you want the easy way, you can union the statements, sum them up and than compare the overall value to 0

```
SELECT SUM(*) FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM teachers WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL;
UNION;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM students WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL;)
```

I've tried writing the query using EXISTS and avoid the counting altogether. However it resulted in a way messier and convoluted query.

From what I know, you can't return a straight up Boolean from SQL, since there is no supported type. Either way you'll have to convert it somehow (a query that return the string "true"/"false" etc)

That's why I think that summing the values and comparing them on your end is best in this case

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to `CROSS JOIN` the two queries together and use a `CASE` expression to determine the result:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN TEACHER_COUNT > 0 OR STUDENT_COUNT > 0 THEN 'FALSE'
         ELSE 'TRUE'
       END
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS TEACHER_COUNT FROM teachers WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL)
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS STUDENT_COUNT FROM students WHERE is_registered IS NOT NULL)
```

Note that the Oracle RDBMS does not have a BOOLEAN data type, so I chose to return the strings `'TRUE'` or `'FALSE'` here. You can use 1/0, 'Y'/'N', or whatever you like.

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b47e29e847056147e8e539832743136b)